# ExtJS browser page refresh lose location

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have my ExtJS application. It's working fine but when I refresh the page it's sending me again to the login page and I lose the location where I was.

Is there any Ext.History implementation for solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, see [Ext.util.History](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.util.History). Btw, the [Ext Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api) site uses History class and I also use it at my examples page: http://extjs.eu/ext-examples/

Comment: Thanks, I just send an email from your website.